# Concat more than one properties in ComboBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I want to concat some properties to show in a ComboBox. I am doing this as the following:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"  
          SelectedItem="{Binding Issue.User, Mode=TwoWay}">
          <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1} {2}">
                                <Binding Path="Name" />
                                <Binding Path="Surname" />
                                <Binding Path="LastModified" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
           </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Why is the selected item not shown properly? Is the DisplayMemberPath not defined by the ItemTemplate?

Comment: Does the ComboBox need to be editable (able to free-type the value)?

Comment: I believe if you define an implicit `DataTemplate` for the item class in `ComboBox`'s resources it could do the trick.

Comment: @Eric: Yes, it does.

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov: I am not sure if I got you right. I am actually defining an implicit DataTemplate in my code.

Comment: @Parisa you need to have that `DataTemplate` in `Combobox.Resources` part, not in `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` as that template must used by `TextBox` which is a part of `ComboBox`'s `ControlTemplate`

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov: Thanks for the explanation. I tried this and put the DataTemplate in the Resources. I assigned it as a StaticResource to the ItemTemplate. Still same problem..

Comment: That's not implicit template. You need a DataTemplate without x:Key attribute for it to be implicit.

Comment: The template has a key!  (I am trying to figure out, how I can put a code in comment!)

Comment: Here how I try to do what you suggest:  <br/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="UserDataTemplate">
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1} {2}">
                        <Binding Path="Name" />
                        <Binding Path="Surname" />
                        <Binding Path="LastModified" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
 And  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserDataTemplate}" in the ComboBox.

Comment: @Parisa What should happen when user edits ComboBox value? Based on that knowledge you can write coverter and bind it to ComboBox's Text property

Comment: @GorRustamyan it is like a normal editable comboBox. Typing something in the comboBox makes it easier to select an item without searching after it in the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

If you can append the EF model, create a read-only property (e.g. Display). Then set the DisplayMemberPath and TextSearch.Text to the same value:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Issue.User, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Display" TextSearch.Text="Display" />
```

Comment: Thanks Eric for the answer. I know that I can edit the VM and get it done in this way. I am curious if it is possible to do it in the Xaml without changing the VM.